# Header error and access-Control-Allow-origin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an API I want to post values using ajax. But I get a Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token , and as I test it I no access.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getFormData($form){
  var unindexed_array = $form.serializeArray();
  var indexed_array = {};

  $.map(unindexed_array, function(n, i){
      indexed_array[n['name']] = n['value'];
  });

  return indexed_array;
}
  var $form = $("#postform");
  var data = getFormData($form);

  $.ajax({
      url: 'https://example/run/t1/go',
      headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *','Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true','X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest','Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      },
     method: 'POST',
     dataType: 'json',
     data: data,
     success: function(data){
       console.log('success: '+data);
     }
   });
  </script>
```

Comment: "scriptsrc" isn't a valid tag as far as I know. You probably meant `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" crossorigin="anonymous"/>`

Comment: Is this inside a javascript file or html? From the way you posted the question it isn't clear. The first line is a html tag and the rest appears to be jquery, which isn't inside a `<script>` tag